# How to schedule a exe file in windows 10

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, exe

I have written a python script which sends msg by email everyday, so I want to give this file to a client, so I have converted to exe file, but I want to schedule the exe file.

Comment: i think you need to open the windows task scheduler and add it ... I imagine you can also do this from the command line somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows 10:

search for "task scheduler"

then choose "Action" from menu click on create task.
Then go to action tab and specify you. exe path which you created in your system.

Choose other task settings as you need and hit ok.

Your scheduler task is ready now but make sure to check it is in "running" state

Comment: I have use the task scheduler, but it is not working for exe files, it is working for script.

Answer (score 0):

For Unix type systems consider crontab. For Windows you can use Task Scheduler

Comment: exe probably means windows :P